# search highlight string with and without Arabic Diacritic characters

Tags: php

Is there a regular expression to match a specific string with and without special characters? Special characters-insensitive, so to speak.

Like sql database keywords=الحمد will match after search highlight=الْحَمْدُ

Edit: I want to match specific strings with and without special/accented characters. Not just any string/character.

```
  function mbStringToArray($string)
    {
        $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
        while($strlen)
        {
            $array[] = mb_substr($string, 0, 1, "UTF-8");
            $string = mb_substr($string, 1, $strlen, "UTF-8");
            $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
        }
        return $array;
    }

    // I had to use this ugly function to remove accents as iconv didn't work properly on my test server.
    function stripAccents($stripAccents){
        return utf8_encode(strtr(utf8_decode($stripAccents),utf8_decode('ِ', 'ُ', 'ٓ', 'ٰ', 'ْ', 'ٌ', 'ٍ', 'ً', 'ّ', 'َ'),''));
    }

    $keywords= 'الحمد';

    $search = '%' . $keywords . '%';
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM quran WHERE $trans LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $search);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();  


    $clientNameNoAccent = stripAccents($clientName);

    $clientNameArray = mbStringToArray($clientName);

    foreach($clientNameArray as $pos => &$char)
    {
        $charNA =$clientNameNoAccent[$pos];
        if($char != $charNA)
        {
            $char = "(?:$char|$charNA|$charNA\p{M})";
        }
    }

    $clientSearchPattern = implode($clientNameArray); // c(?:é|e|e\p{M})ra

    if($stmt->execute()){
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){   
            $text = 'الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ';
            $search = preg_replace('/(.*?)(' . $clientSearchPattern . ')(.*?)/iu', '$1<span class="highlight">$2</span>$3', $text);         
        echo $search;// لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ<span class="highlight">الْحَمْدُ</span>
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a method to generate dynamic regex patterns for keywords (entered by the user) to consider Arabic or Persian (Farsi) accents (diacritics/tashkeel marks/eraab). This can be used to highlight keywords in the string and/or cut long text based on keywords to be shown in the search results. I hope this will help someone!

```
private function generateRegexPattern(string $keyword): string
    {
        $pattern = '';

        // Convert the keyword to an array of characters
        $letters = preg_split('//u', $keyword, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

        $lastLoop = array_key_last($letters);

        // Loop through each character in the keyword
        foreach ($letters as $key => $letter) {

            // Check if the character is an Arabic or Persian letter
            if (preg_match('/ا|أ|إ/u', $letter)) {
                // If it is, add a character class with the letter and any possible variations
                $pattern .= "(ا|أ|إ)";
            } elseif (preg_match('/ؤ|و/u', $letter)) {
                $pattern .= "(ؤ|و)";
            } elseif (preg_match('/ة|ه/u', $letter)) {
                $pattern .= "(ة|ه)";
            } else {
                // If it's not, add the character as-is
                $pattern .= $letter;
            }

            ($key !== $lastLoop) ? $pattern .= '[\x{064B}-\x{0655}]{0,2}' : $pattern .= '';
        }

        return $pattern;

    }
```

Comment: Why use pipes instead of a character class for those 2 and 3 character lists? This way you can avoid the capturing parentheses.